Getting the model source from loaded Pytorch pt2 file
I am trying to debug a PyTorch model that has been pretrained and exported as a .pt2 file but I only have access to the inference code that loads the model.
Is there any way to recover the class file of the model, modify it, and use the same weights in the .pt2 file?
